# I keep getting this Server Error - Error: The default export is not a React Component in page: "/products/all"

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I wanted to make a page for all my listed products that I have in server.json (below is the file)

```
{
  "products": [

    {
      "slug": "live-by-the-sun-love-by-the-moon",      
      "title": "Live by the sun, love by the moon.",
      "price": "40,99",
      "published_at": "2021-01-22 16:35:40",
      "thumbnail": "https://storage.googleapis.com/golden-wind/nextlevelweek/05-podcastr/opensource.jpg",
      "description": "<p>Camiseta feita com tecido totalmente artesanal, fabricada com algodão 99%</p>"
    },
    {
      "slug": "believe-in-your-visions",       
      "title": "Believe in your visions",
      "price": "59,90",
      "published_at": "2021-01-15 13:00:00",
      "thumbnail": "https://storage.googleapis.com/golden-wind/nextlevelweek/05-podcastr/funcional.jpg",
      "description": "<p>Camiseta feita com tecido totalmente artesanal, fabricada com algodão 99%, disponível em branco, azul e preto</p>\n"
    }
  ]
}
```

but I keep getting this error, I think something is wrong with my /pages/products/all.tsx file (below too) and I don't know what it is.

```
import styles from "./all.module.scss"
import products from "../../../server.json"
import Link from "next/link"

type products = [{

    slug: string; 
    title: string; 
    price: string; 
    published_at: string; 
    thumbnail: string; 
    description: string;
    
}]

type ProductList = {
    products: products
}

export function allProducts({ products }: ProductList) {

    {products.map(product =>
        <div key={product.slug} className={styles.wholeProduct}>
            <Link href={`products/${product.slug}`}>
                <a>
                    <div className={styles.productRow}>
                        <div className={styles.productColumnImage}>
                            {product.thumbnail}
                        </div>
                        <div className={styles.productColumn}>
                            {product.title} {product.price}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </Link>
        </div>
    )}
}
```

I'm kinda new to nextJS so I'm sorry if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your component file doesn't have a default export. Either change your import to:

```js
import {allProducts as products} from "../../../server.json"
```

OR make it the `default` export:

```js
export default function allProducts({ products }: ProductList) {
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I did that and it worked, the only thing I changed is that I made the function and than exported afterwards because I was declaring props below, but now it works just fine, thanks